# Pulling Text Area Data from MySQL into existing HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I have a form that I have created for internal use.  I have been able to populate the MySQL database with the data from the form.  I have also created a search function that will pull the data back into the fields based on an ID key (in this case a number).  All of the text fields come back into the fields, but the Text Area data does not.  I go to the MySQL database, and the table fields for those Text Areas are filled in, but they don't seem to pull back into the form.  Please help me if you can.  Thank you.

**My HTML form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>- - = =  EPC Print Order Form = = - -  </title>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#DFDFD9">

<h1>Digital Print Form &nbsp &nbsp<input type="image" src="http://commonmedia.asicentral.com/180000/182101/EPC_KAPP.jpg"></h1>

<!-- form to get key detail of record in database -->
<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Request RFQ</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><form name="form" method="POST" action="form1.php">
RFQ#:</td><td><input type="text" name="search"></td><td><input type="submit"  value="submit"></td>
</form></tr></table>
</fieldset>

<!---------------------  Print Form Data ------------------>

<form action="mysqlTest.php" method="post" id="prayfrm" name="prayfrm" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" onreset="return confirm('Do you want to clear this form?')">
<input type="hidden" name="drfq" value="6">

<!--**********   Basic Job Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Job Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
        <td><label for="drepid">Sales Rep</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="drepid" size="30" required="true"/>
        </td>
        <td><label>Today's Date</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="datepicker" size="10"/></td>
</tr>     
<tr>
<td><label for="repemail">Rep Email</label></td>
<td><input id="repemail" name="repemail" type="text" size="30" required="true" /></td>
<td><label>Date Needed</label></td>
<td><input id="dateneeded" name="dateneeded" type="text" size="10" required="true" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="description">Description</label></td>
<td><input id="description" name="description" type="text" size="30" required="true" /></td>
<td><label for="qty">Quantity</label></td>
<td><input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" size="10" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="pgsizeh">Page Size (h) x (w)</label></td>
<td><input id="pgsizeh" name="pgsizeh" type="text" size="10" required="true" />  x  <input id="pgsizew" name="pgsizew" type="text" size="13" required="true" /></td>
<td><label for="pageno">Page Number</label></td>
<td><input id="pageno" name="pageno" type="text" size="10" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="stock">Stock</label></td>
<td><input id="stock" name="stock" type="text" size="10" required="true" /> &nbsp<label for="stock">Color &nbsp </label>
<input type="text" name="ink" size="6" required="true"/>
</td>

<td><label for="inknote"> &nbsp Explain </label></td>
<td><input id="inknote" name="inknote" type="text" size="10" /></td>                    

</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="rfq">Referenced RFQ:</label></td>
<td><input id="rfq" name="rfq" type="text" size="10" required="true" /><td><label for="finishing">Finishing</label></td>
<td><input id="finishing" name="finishing" type="text" size="10" required="true" />
</tr>

</table></fieldset>

<!--**********  Customer Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Customer Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><label for="dfirstname">First Name</label></td><td><input id="dfirstname" name="dfirstname" type="text" size="31" required="true" /></td><td><label for="dlastname">&nbsp Last </label></td><td><input id="dlastname" name="dlastname" type="text" size="31" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="dorganization">Organization</label></td>
<td><input id="dorganization" name="dorganization" type="text" size="31" required="true" /></td><td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
<td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="31" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="daddress1">Address</label></td><td><input id="daddress1" name="daddress1" type="text" size="31" required="true" /><td></td><td><input id="daddress2" name="daddress2" type="text" size="31" />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="dcity">City</label></td><td><input id="dcity" name="dcity" type="text" size="25" required="true" /> <label for="dstate"> State</label></td><td><input id="dstate" name="dstate" type="text" size="3" required="true" /> <td><label for="dzip"> Zip </label> <input id="dzip" name="dzip" type="text" size="27" required="true" /></tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="phone">Phone </label><td><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="31" required="true" /></td><td><label for="fax">Fax </label><td><input id="fax" name="fax" type="text" size="31" required="true" /> </td>
</tr></table></fieldset>

<!--**********  Delivery Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Delivery Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><label for="proof">Proof?</label>&nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="proof" value="yes"  required="true" />&nbsp </td><td><label for="whoproof">Proof to Whom?</label> <input id="whoproof" name="whoproof" type="text" size="44" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="quote">Quote?</label>&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="quote" value="yes" required="true" />&nbsp </td>
<td><label for="amount">Amount: $</label> <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" size="50" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="delivery">Delivery Instructions</label></td><td><textarea name="delivery" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="notes">Additional Notes</label></td><td><textarea name="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</tr>
<td align="right"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td align="left"><input name="Reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" /></table></fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

**My PHP File for adding fields to database**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'hostname';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = '*******';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'dbasename';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Field Names
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

$drepid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['drepid']);
$datepicker=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
$repemail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['repemail']);
$dateneeded=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateneeded']);
$description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$qty=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty']);
$pgsizeh=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pgsizeh']);
$pgsizew=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pgsizew']);
$pageno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pageno']);
$stock=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
$ink=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ink']);
$inknote=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inknote']);
$rfq=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rfq']);
$finishing=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['finishing']);
$dfirstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dfirstname']);
$dlastname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dlastname']);
$dorganization=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dorganization']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$daddress1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['daddress1']);
$daddress2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['daddress2']);
$dcity=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dcity']);
$dstate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dstate']);
$dzip=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dzip']);
$phone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$fax=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fax']);
$proof=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['proof']);
$whoproof=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['whoproof']);
$quote=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quote']);
$amount=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);
$delivery=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delivery']);
$notes=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO epc_print (drepid, datepicker, repemail, dateneeded, description, qty, pgsizeh, pgsizew, pageno, stock, ink, inknote, rfq, finishing, dfirstname, dlastname, dorganization, email, daddress1, daddress2, dcity, dstate, dzip, phone, fax, proof, whoproof, quote, amount, delivery, notes) values ('$drepid', '$datepicker', '$repemail', '$dateneeded', '$description', '$qty', '$pgsizeh', '$pgsizew', '$pageno', '$stock', '$ink', '$inknote', 'rfq', '$finishing', '$dfirstname', '$dlastname', '$dorganization', '$email', '$daddress1', '$daddress2', '$dcity', '$dstate', '$dzip', '$phone', '$fax', '$proof', '$whoproof', '$quote', '$amount', '$delivery', '$notes')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "
<code><pre></code>";
echo "POST:";
print_r($_POST);
echo "<code></pre></code>
";
echo "1 record added";


?>
```

**Then my php file to retrieve data:**

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('hostname','username','*****') or die ("Couldn't connect to server."); 
$db = mysql_select_db('databasename', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

$search=$_POST['search'];

$data = 'SELECT * FROM `epc_print` WHERE `drfq` = "'.$search.'"';
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
  $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);


?> 


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
      <title>- - = = EPC Print Form = = - - </title>
 </head>

<body bgcolor="#DFDFD9">

<h1>Digital Print Form &nbsp &nbsp<input type="image" src="http://commonmedia.asicentral.com/180000/182101/EPC_KAPP.jpg"></h1>

<!-- form to get key detail of record in database -->
<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Request RFQ</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><form name="form" method="POST" action="form1.php">
RFQ#:</td><td><input type="text" name="search"></td><td><input type="submit"  value="submit"></td>
</form></tr></table>
</fieldset>

<!---------------------  Print Form Data ------------------>

<form action="form2.php" method="post" id="prayfrm" name="prayfrm" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" onreset="return confirm('Do you want to clear this form?')">
<input type="hidden" name="drfq" value="6">

<!--**********   Basic Job Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Job Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
        <td><label for="drepid">Sales Rep</label></td>
        <td><input id="drepid" name="drepid" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[drepid])?>" required="true" /></td>


      </td>
        <td><label>Today's Date</label></td>
<td><input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[datepicker])?>" required="true" /></td>

</tr>     
<tr>
<td><label for="repemail">Rep Email</label></td>
<td><input id="repemail" name="repemail" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[repemail])?>" required="true" /></td>
<td><label>Date Needed</label></td>
<td><input id="dateneeded" name="dateneeded" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dateneeded])?>" required="true" /></td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="description">Description</label></td>
<td><input id="description" name="description" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[description])?>" required="true" /></td>
<td><label for="qty">Quantity</label></td>
<td><input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[qty])?>"required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="pgsizeh">Page Size (h) x (w)</label></td>
<td><input id="pgsizeh" name="pgsizeh" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[pgsizeh])?>" required="true" />  x  <input id="pgsizew" name="pgsizew" type="text" size="14" value="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars ($data2[pgsizew])?>" required="true" /></td>
<td><label for="pageno">Page Number</label></td>
<td><input id="pageno" name="pageno" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[pageno])?>" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="stock">Stock</label></td>
<td><input id="stock" name="stock" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[stock])?>" required="true" /> <label for="ink">Color </label> <input id="ink" name="ink" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[ink])?>" required="true" /></td>

<td><label for="inknote"> &nbsp Explain </label></td>
<td><input id="inknote" name="inknote" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[inknote])?>"/></td>                 

</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="rfq">Referenced RFQ:</label></td>
<td><input id="rfq" name="rfq" type="text" size="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[rfq])?>" required="true"/></td> <td><label for="finishing">Finishing</label></td>
<td><input id="finishing" name="finishing" type="text" size="10" value= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[finishing])?>" required="true" />
</tr>

</table></fieldset>

<!--**********  Customer Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Customer Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><label for="dfirstname">First Name</label></td><td><input id="dfirstname" name="dfirstname" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dfirstname])?>" required="true" /></td><td><label for="dlastname">&nbsp Last </label></td><td><input id="dlastname" name="dlastname" type="text" size="31" value= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dlastname])?>"required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="dorganization">Organization</label></td>
<td><input id="dorganization" name="dorganization" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dorganization])?>" required="true" /></td><td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
<td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[email])?>" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="daddress1">Address</label></td><td><input id="daddress1" name="daddress1" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[daddress1])?>" required="true" /><td></td><td><input id="daddress2" name="daddress2" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[daddress2])?>"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="dcity">City</label></td><td><input id="dcity" name="dcity" type="text" size="25" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dcity])?>" required="true" /> <label for="dstate"> State</label></td><td><input id="dstate" name="dstate" type="text" size="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dstate])?>" required="true" /> <td><label for="dzip"> Zip </label> <input id="dzip" name="dzip" type="text" size="27" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[dzip])?>" required="true" /></tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="phone">Phone </label><td><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[phone])?>" required="true" /></td><td><label for="fax">Fax </label><td><input id="fax" name="fax" type="text" size="31" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[fax])?>"/> </td>
</tr></table></fieldset>

<!--**********  Delivery Information for the form******************-->

<fieldset style='width:570px; text-align:left; border-width:2px;'>
<legend><h3>Delivery Information</h3></legend>
<table bgcolor="beige" border="0" width="570px">
<tr>
<td><label for="proof">Proof?</label>&nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="proof" value="<?php echo ($data2[proof])?>" />&nbsp </td><td><label for="whoproof">Proof to Whom?</label> <input id="whoproof" name="whoproof" type="text" size="44" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[whoproof])?>"required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="quote">Quote?</label>&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="quote" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[quote])?>" required="true" />&nbsp </td>
<td><label for="amount">Amount: $</label> <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[amount])?>" required="true" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="delivery">Delivery Instructions</label></td><td><textarea name="delivery" rows="4" cols="50" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[delivery])?>" /></textarea></tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="notes">Additional Notes</label></td><td><textarea name="notes" rows="4" cols="50" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($data2[notes])?>"/></textarea>
</tr>
<td align="right"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
<td align="left"><input name="Reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" /></table></fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: `<code><pre></code>` is not valid html... maybe this is just for debugging, but it should still be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The default value of a text area is provided by the text node inside the element, not a value attribute.

```
<textarea>Default value
Which can have new lines</textarea>
```

Comment: Change `<textarea value=something></textarea>` to `<textarea>something</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

`value` isn't a valid attribute for textareas, you need to use `<textarea>value</textarea>`